# ERROR: Failed to determine the health of the cluster. Unexpected http status [503]

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi I trying to install elk on ubuntu20.04 and I used this resource https://kifarunix.com/install-elk-stack-8-x-on-ubuntu/ but when I want to run `/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token -s kibana` I get the flowing error

`ERROR: Failed to determine the health of the cluster. Unexpected http status [503]` 
how can I fix this?

pleas help me!!!

Comment: A good start to any question is what version of Ubuntu you are using. Please EDIT the question and add this info. You may also want to give this a read https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for your tips@David. I have edited my question. Please help me if you can

Comment: I looked at the link you gave. That is quite a long complex install. Are you sure you did not mess up or miss something?

Comment: To be honest, no, I'm not sure

Comment: I put `-Xms512m` and `-Xmx512m` into `/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options`   Could this be the problem?

Comment: No idea I do not know that app.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running elasticsearch on a single node? If so, check if you have the line `cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["localhost"]` uncommented on the elasticsearch.yml file. Comment the line and add `discovery.type: single-node` on the next line. Restart elasticsearch and check. Check on this link too [[Error] Setup-passwords: Failed to determine the health of the cluster](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/error-setup-passwords-failed-to-determine-the-health-of-the-cluster/207649)

Hope this helps.